# How to use static columns inside clustering keys in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    user_id text,
    add_id  text,
    other_user_id text,
    date timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, add_id, other_user_id)
);
```

And I want to share the column date not for the hole partition (that is user_id) but for the **user_ud/add_id** level.

So what I want is something similar to making **date a static column**, but with **add_id** in consideration.

Example of desired Table:

```
'user1'  'add1'  'otheruser1' date1
'user1'  'add1'  'otheruser2' date1
'user1'  'add1'  'otheruser3' date1

'user1'  'add2'  'otheruser4' date2
'user1'  'add2'  'otheruser5' date2
'user1'  'add2'  'otheruser6' date2
```

(*the space in the midle is for explanation purpose)
**This is posible? if so, how?**

**MORE EXPLANATION:**

In a **relational database** the relations would be one table with:
`[ user_id(pk)  |  add_id(pk)  |  date ]`

pk: primary key

The other_user_id in the Cassandra table is an experiment I am doing to improve read time from Cassandra at costs of penalizing the write time

Thanks!

Comment: Could you describe your use case(s) of how you would be reading data from this table (Query Patterns). I think the context would help with developing some alternative data model. For example: depending on your use case you could just make add_id a timeuuid and it could (potentially) serve double duty as a unique id and a timestamp.

Comment: Hi @fromanator I don' t want to make time part of the primary keys because y want to prevent from having two rows with the same user_id and add_id but with different time.Thanks for asking!

Comment: Would it work for you if you used a compound partition key `(user_id, add_id)`? Your static column would be associated with a `(user_id, add_id)` pair. So your full primary key would look like `primary key ((user_id, add_id), other_user_id)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently **not possible** to have a static column on the clustering level. I created a **[JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10533)** here but it was dismissed

Comment: Thank you @doanduyhai!, I was hoping that there was a solution :(

Comment: @George You can vote for this ticket. If there are enough people requesting for this feature, they may re-open it. I am convinced that a static clustering column is sensible for some use-cases

Comment: I wouldn't get your hopes up of getting that feature anytime soon. IMO the way static columns as implemented now could be called an "elegant hack" on top of the existing storage engine. To implement static columns as proposed would require significant re-work of the storage engine to implement properly.

Answer (score 0):

If your date going to remain same for each `add_id`, then I would suggest use `date` as a primary key instead of `other_user_id`.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    user_id text,
    add_id  text,
    date timestamp,
    other_user_id text,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, add_id, date)
);
```

It will create partition having single key `(user1, add1, date1)`
and records will be:

```
'otheruser1'
'otheruser2'
'otheruser3'
```

Comment: Hi @Vitthal, I don' t want to make date a primary key because that can make me have two (or more)  user_id, add_id with different dates.